# Spring LDAP, check the membership of user in specified group

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap, spring-ldap

I'm creating an app with a special privileges for a user which is in specified group in LDAP, I'm logging in using spring security, but I have no idea how to check the group of the user.
 The goal is to show all of the ldap users table with data, and if someone belongs to a group in ldap it shows also buttons to change that data.

So how to check belonging to group of an LDAP user?

Greetings, Rafał !

Answer (score 0):

Use this to verify authentication of user in specific group

```
 FilterBasedLdapUserSearch search = new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch(
  "OU=users,DC=mycompany,DC=com",
  "(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName={0})" +
  "(memberof:=CN=entergroup,OU=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=com)" +")", contextsource );
```

hope this helps.